# Apache AH00526: ErrorLog not allowed here

Tags: log-files, httpd.conf, apache2

By default, Apache prevents access to .htaccess and .htpasswd files with this directive in apache2.conf

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Any request for any matching file, produces a line in the error log

```
authz_core:error AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /.html
```

I just want to put these kind of errors on a separate log file, but Apache does not accept this directive:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/separate.log
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

**AH00526: Syntax error ErrorLog not allowed here**

So, what's the correct syntax in order to log these requests on a separate file?

Comment: See the section on **conditional logs** in the manual: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Answer (score 1):

Try something along this line:

Set an environment variable with `SetEnvIf` and use this as condition for a conditional log statement. Example from the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.gif$ gif-image
CustomLog "gif-requests.log" common env=gif-image
```

This would log all gif requests into a special log file.

Comment: How do gif images fit in? I asked FilesMatch "^\.ht"

Comment: And how does CustomLog fits in? I asked for ErrorLog.

Comment: @DemisPalmaツ: This is an example copied from the docs. You are supposed to adapt it to your situation. Also, this method will log these requests in a separate file, like you asked.

Comment: I don't see how 'Request_URI \.gif$' can be adapted to match 'FilesMatch "^\.ht"'. Could you please edit the answer according to the question?